# WinRT trying to display Grouped items in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to convince a ListBox to show grouped items by binding a nested Collection to it. I've got it to display the group headers, but the items do not show. I was vaguely trying to follow [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780627.aspx), specifically the second part, "To use a data source where each item contains a collection of child items", but I don't really get their approach (two CollectionViewSources I can understand, the one containing groups bound to GridView makes sense, but the other (items in group) bound to a ListView that has no name and seems to not be used anywhere... what?). I'm trying to do it in as minimal way as possible (no fancy styling and groupheaderselectors, i can add those later, now all I need is to display the items at all), and so far I am unsuccesful.

I know this is poorly formulated question, but I'm still struggling with all the WPF concepts, so I'm unable to ask better. Below is my current code that displays groups, but not their items, could anyone please help&explain why it doesn't work and show how to modify it so it works? I need it to use the nested collections approach, and I need it to be as simple as possible, thanks.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Bulsitpokusy.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Bulsitpokusy"
    xmlns:dt="using:Bulsitpokusy.Data"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <dt:MpViewmodel></dt:MpViewmodel>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListItemsView.View}">
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="False">

                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="600"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MpViewmodel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace Bulsitpokusy.Data
{
    public class MpGroup
    {
        public string Title;
        public ObservableCollection<string> ChildItems;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Title;
        }
    }

    public class MpViewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MpGroup> listItems = new ObservableCollection<MpGroup>()
        {
            new MpGroup(){Title="Grupa 1", ChildItems=new ObservableCollection<string>{
                "G1.I1", "G1.I2", "G1.I3"
            }},
            new MpGroup(){Title="Grupa 2", ChildItems=new ObservableCollection<string>{
                "G2.I1", "G2.I2", "G2.I3"
            }}
        };

        public CollectionViewSource ListItemsView
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public MpViewmodel()
        {
            ListItemsView = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = listItems, IsSourceGrouped=true, ItemsPath=new Windows.UI.Xaml.PropertyPath("ChildItems") };
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Everything else is default - as generated by the "Windows Store -> Blank App (XAML)" template.
Thank you for any useful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use [grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.issourcegrouped.aspx). What you're trying to do is to display child items and for that you need to create `ItemTemplate` with `ItemsControl` which will display your child items as at the moment by default it will call only `ToString()` on each item and display that

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

also change your fields into properties as you cannot bind to fields:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<string> ChildItems { get; set; }
```

Comment: Okay, now, if you are willing, how would I go about this using grouping on WinRT, where CollectionViewSource doesn't have Filter and Group functions, and I want the whole structure to be Two-way bindable, so getting the "current filtered+grouped viewmodel" by linq isn't an option? Or is there a (built-in, non-manual) way to make changes to linq result propagate to the original collection?

Comment: I've updated my answer with correct link to WinRT which should give you more idea about grouping using `CollectionViewSource` but to be honest don't see a point in your case. It's useful if you have flat list that should be grouped for view and your list is already structured so it's easier to create `DataTemplate` and grouping, in this particular case, may cause you more issues then benefits.